# How to make an horizontal ProgressBar match a TextView size

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-progressbar

I want my ProgressBar to match the size of my `TextView` so to make it shorter or longer depending on what I have written in my `TextView`.

Here is my XML :

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_file_icon"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_file"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="22sp"
          android:text="Filename" />
      <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/pb_file"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:max="100"
          android:minWidth="200dp"
          android:progress="0"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can try using a different layout like RelativeLayout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Text I want to display" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/pb_file"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
       android:max="100"
       android:progress="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```